# Why thymleaf can't read this expression : "${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_ADMIN'')')}

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I tried to get Role name (i.e : ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER) to assign view dpendly of the role. I used this code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;


    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.
        jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);



    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.
            authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/","/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/users","/roles").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/projects")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

    }

     @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/webjars/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**","/fonts/**","/libs/**");
        }



<div th:if="${#authorization?.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_ADMIN'')')}">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
                <li><a href="/users">Usuarios</a></li>

                <li><a href="/roles">Roles</a></li>

                <li><a href="/professionalExperiences">Experiencia <br />Profesional
                </a></li>

                <li><a href="/professinal_skills">Professional <br />Skills
                </a></li>

                <li><a href="/personal_skills">Personal <br />Skills
                </a></li>

                <li><a href="/projects">Proyectos</a></li>

                <li><a href="/academics">Formacion<br /> Academica
                </a></li>

                <li><a href="/certifications">Cartificaciones</a></li>

                <li><a href="/courses">Cursos</a></li>

                <li><a href="/language_evals">Evaluacion<br /> del idioma
                </a></li>

            </ul>
            </div>
```

when i run the project after try to login i got this error :
EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method expression(java.lang.String) on null context object
i added a ? after #authorization but the same problem
I'm using : Spring Boot, thymleaf, Maven,

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
```

Comment: with this i can access but without control if is an ROLE_ADMIN or ROLE_USER :
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
    <li><a href="/users">Usuarios</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
 <li>Teeeeeeeeeeeeeessstttt</li>
 
 </ul>
 </div>

Comment: Are you sure than your user does not have both roles or the roles are not defined hierarchically? Can you make a test with a user that has only the ROLE_USER?

Comment: the roles are configured in WebSecurityConfig : .antMatchers("/","/login").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/users","/roles").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
    .and() .... etc
i sure the the user have only one role

Comment: Where do you give each users a role? In addition, can you try to add the following div in your page and let me know what is the output <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
            Logged in user: <span sec:authentication="name"></span> |
            Roles: <span sec:authentication="principal.authorities"></span>
            
        </div>

Comment: the result is :
Logged in user:  | Roles:  ,I've thought that spring can get the role from the WebSecurityConf

Comment: I think that in the WebSecurityConf you have configured what pages need authentication and what pages need a specific role to be accessed

Comment: in the WebSecurityConf i configured that the links : /users and /roles are accessibly only from ROLE_ADMIN i'ts work fine but in want to hide Uers and Roles options from ROLE_USER menu, now the user can view USer and Role options in the menu but cannot access

Comment: Who cannot access user and role options?The user that has role admin?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, just do the check in the li for example <li sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"><a href="/roles">Roles</a></li> and delete the sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" from the div

Comment: what is the problem?